# Alpha 7 Camera API Shutter Speed

Tags: camera, sony

I was trying to implement a long exposure timer for the Sony Alpha 7 using the Remote Camera API. Is it possible to set the shutter speed using the API to BULB? Also, is it possible to control the exposure time from within an app when the shutter is set to BULB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope Sony will implement these features, otherwise the API is kind of useless for many scenarios. 
Here is an interesting article about exactly this demand: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/09/10/new-sony-camera-remote-api-leaves-developers-wanting-more/

I would be very happy to know if the features will be implemented in the future.
Knowing this we could already start developing apps otherwise it makes no sense...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry at this time those features are not available in the API.  Will let you know if they are implemented in the future.